# ¿como usar el enlace href para php?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, xampp, aplicación-web

Ya tengo un archivo index.php
Un archivo admin.php que esta en una carpeta módulos, que esta junto a index.php en una carpeta proyectos.
En index.php

```
     <a href="?p=admin"><Administrador</a>
```

Intento entrar en admin.php que contiene su usario y password. pero no me carga o abre admin.php, asi que uso:

```
     <a href="modulos/admin.php"><Administrador</a>
```

Y recien me abre admin.php, pero en una nueva pestaña y no me actualiza el index.php.
Solo queria saber la diferencia de href="?p=admin" junto a usar una direccion mas directa href="modulos/admin.php" cual seria mas correcto.

Comment: No es que alguna sea correcta y la otra incorrecta, sino que depende de cómo estás armando tu proyecto y cuál te da mejores resultados. Personalmente, prefiero la segunda forma.

Answer (score 0):

Ambos son correctos.

La diferencia tiene que ver con el comportamiento por defector del atributo `href` de la etiqueta `<a>`

Generalmente el atributo espera una URL absoluta, por ejemplo `https://www.wikipedia.org`, que cuente con toda la información del recurso: protocolo, host, etc. De lo contrario, se considera una URL relativa. En tu caso ambas URL se [interpretan como relativas](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808#section-2) y heredan la información base del servidor que se utilice.

En el caso de:

```
<a href="?p=admin"><Administrador</a>
```

Ya que comienza con `?` se interpreta como un componente `query` y solamente se redirige a la URL base la información encontrada después del carácter `?`.

En el caso de:

```
<a href="modulos/admin.php"><Administrador</a>
```

Se interpreta como un `path` relativo y solamente se redirige a la URL base agregándole el contenido del atributo.

En [este enlace](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808#section-4) se puede conocer más sobre cómo se resuelven URL relativas.